# Mysql: Add a column and fill in

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

Table1:

```
Id value
1  10
2  20
3  30
4  40
```

In table 2:

```
Id 
1
1
2
2
3
4
4
4
```

I want to get the results:

Table2:

```
Id  value
1   10
1   10
2   20
2   20
3   30
4   40
4   40
4   40
```

I know add a column with following code:

```
ALTER table Table2  ADD value int(11)
```

How to fill the data??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think these SQL useful to you.

```
  UPDATE Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.id = Table1.id
    SET Table2.value = Table1.value
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you need to first **ALTER** the table and then fill the values using **JOIN** command as:

```
ALTER table Table2  ADD value int(11);
```

Then insert / fill the values as:

```
UPDATE Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 
ON Table2.id = Table1.id
SET Table2.value = Table1.value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run this update command juste after tours.

```
UPDATE Table2 SET value = (SELECT value FROM Table1 WHERE Table2.Id = Table1.Id)
```